# Apache Spark Read One Complex JSON File Per Record RDD or DF

Tags: json, apache-spark

I have an HDFS directory full of the following JSON file format:

https://www.hl7.org/fhir/bundle-transaction.json.html

What I am hoping to do is find an approach to flatten each individual file to become one df record or rdd tuple.  I have tried everything I could think of using read.json(), wholeTextFiles(), etc.

If anyone has any best practices advice or pointers, it would be sincerely appreciated.

Comment: I looked through that json, if u want to have a tuple, what r u expecting to be the key? example helps

Comment: Why does wholeTextFiles not work for you?

Comment: @Pangea This instance is slightly different than what I have.  In my FHIR bundles, there are always only one identifying patient resource.  So ideally using the uuid which would be unique per file.  I hope that is not too vague.

Comment: @JustinPihony Well, I can read the example successfully with sc.wholeTextFiles(), but I am drawing a blank on how to proceed to flatten them effectively thereafter given the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load via `wholeTextFiles` something like this:

```
sc.wholeTextFiles(...) //RDD[(FileName, JSON)
  .map(...processJSON...) //RDD[JsonObject]
```

Then, you can simply call the `.toDF` method so that it will infer from your `JsonObject`.

As far as the `processJSON` method, you could just use something like the [`Play` json parser](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaJson)

Comment: That could certainly be a way.  I'm not that familiar with the Play json parser.  Just now moving pyspark to scala spark.  Thanks for the tip.  I'll take a look.

Comment: Well, while I think this is a potential option, wholeTextFiles appears to be particularly memory hungry.  I'll have to give some thought to the "processJSON" flattening step as well.  Given that a bundle can contain an arbitrary # of resources AND arbitrary nesting depth of those resources, think this bit will the tricky part.

Answer (score -1):

mapPartitions is used when having to deal with data that is structured in a way that different elements can be on different lines.  I've worked with both JSON and XML using mapPartitions.

mapPartitions works on an entire block of data at a time, as opposed to a single element.  While you should be able to use the DataFrameReader API with JSON, mapPartitions can definitely do as you'd like.  I don't have the exact code to flatten a JSON file, but I'm sure you can figure it out.  Just remember the output must be an iterable type.