# How to parse a multiline json in dataset apache spark java

Tags: java, json, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

Is there any way to parse a multi-line json file using Dataset
here is sample code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // creating spark session
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
                .config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value").getOrCreate();

    Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().json("D:/sparktestio/input.json");
    df.show();
}
```

it works perfectly if json is in a single line,but i need it for multi line

My json file

```
{
  "name": "superman",
  "age": "unknown",
  "height": "6.2",
  "weight": "flexible"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache Spark Read One Complex JSON File Per Record RDD or DF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34646232/apache-spark-read-one-complex-json-file-per-record-rdd-or-df)

Comment: @rahul: what is the problem you are facing while accessing this json file?

Comment: my json has white spaces and the dataset reads single line json files contaning a whole object so is unable to parse it response :+--------------------+
|     _corrupt_record|
+--------------------+
|                   {|
|  "name": "superm...|
|   "age": "unknown",|
|    "height": "6.2",|
|  "weight": "flex...|
|                   }|
+--------------------+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last time I checked Spark SQL docs, this stood out:

> Note that the file that is offered as a json file is not a typical
>   JSON file. Each line must contain a separate, self-contained valid
>   JSON object. As a consequence, a regular multi-line JSON file will
>   most often fail.

I've been able to address this in the past by loading the JSON using the Spark Context `wholeTextFiles` method which produces a PairRDD.

See complete example in the "Spark SQL JSON Example Tutorial Part 2" section on this page https://www.supergloo.com/fieldnotes/spark-sql-json-examples/

Answer (score 4):

The apache spark documentation clearly mention this -

For a regular multi-line JSON file, set the multiLine option to true.

Therefore, the solution is

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().option("multiLine", true).json("file:/a/b/c.json");
df.show();
```

I have tried the json with the same format (one single json object across multiple lines).  After adding the option, I no longer see the result with `corrupted_record` header in result any more.

Answer (score 2):

```
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Java Spark Hive Example")
            .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();

    JavaRDD<Tuple2<String, String>> javaRDD = spark.sparkContext().wholeTextFiles(filePath, 1).toJavaRDD();

    List<Tuple2<String, String>> collect = javaRDD.collect();
    System.out.println("everything =  " + everything);
```